# Does spring FORM_LOGIN_FILTER support ConcurrentSessionControl?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I am doing a basic spring security setup. This is my spring-security.xml configuration:

```
<http auto-config='false' entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
        <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="authenticationFilter" />
        <logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" logout-success-url="/" />
        <!-- <session-management > <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" 
            expired-url="/"/> </session-management> -->
            <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"/>
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationFilter" class="com.diners.security.AuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/index.jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
        <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
        <beans:property name="expiredUrl" value="/" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="sas"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry"
            ref="sessionRegistry" />
        <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sessionRegistry"
        class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="kalai"
                    password="test"
                    authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <user name="magesh"
                    password="test"
                    authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

I am using a custom form login filter. I want concurrency control for login so that the user can have only one session at a moment. He should not be able to login in another browser until his current session expires or he manually logs out.

Some state that adding the below listener will resolve the issue. So i added the below in web.xml

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

But it didn't help me either. Then i found in some posts that form login filter will not support concurrentsessioncontrol.

Do i need to implement any stuff? Can anyone suggest something on this or can you provide alternatives for the requirement? I have a custom filter for providing json response on successful and unsuccessful authentication.

Any helping hands will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it supports. add the following to your `authenticationFilter` bean

```
    <property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" />
```